# log4j child class not overriding root class configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

Can someone give me pointers on below. I tought the child class level (trace) should override the root class level (warn), but I only see the warn and above logs.

[image]
I tought the child class level (trace) should override the root class level (warn). but I only see the warn and above logs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="warn"  monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="StdOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        
        <File name="FileAppender" filename="LogOutput.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>   
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>

        <!--  Uncomment the Logger definition below to have ONLY warn-level messages 
        and above be directed to the console -->
        
        <Logger name="com.fdmgroup.logging.Demo" >
            <AppenderRef ref="StdOut" level="trace"/>
        </Logger> 
        
        <Logger name="com.fdmgroup.exercise.Runner" >
            <AppenderRef ref="StdOut" level="trace"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" level="trace"/>
        </Logger> 
    
        

    </Loggers>  
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set a `TRACE` threshold on the logger, but on the appender reference. Hence your "com.fdmgroup.logging.Demo" logger has a:

- `WARN` threshold for the logger (inherited from the root logger),
- a `TRACE` threshold for the "StdOut" appender,
- no threshold for the "FileAppender" inherited from the root logger (the default value for `additivity` is `true).

A message is logged only if it not rejected by filter on the logger and the appender, hence only `WARN` messages are logged.

You probably wanted to set the level for loggers, not appender refs:

```xml
    <Loggers>   
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.fdmgroup.logging.Demo" additivity="false" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="StdOut"/>
        </Logger>     
        <Logger name="com.fdmgroup.exercise.Runner" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="StdOut"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
```